# How I can get "Some text" from alias, when tag = "number" using C#?

Tags: c#, xml

```
                  <w:sdtPr>
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
                        <w:kern w:val="2"/>
                        <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                        <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
                        <w:highlight w:val="yellow"/>
                        <w:lang w:val="uk-UA"/>
                    </w:rPr>
                    <w:alias w:val="Some text"/>
                    <w:tag w:val="number"/>
                    <w:id w:val="-8449093"/>
                    <w:placeholder>
                        <w:docPart w:val="DefaultPlaceholder_-1854013440"/>
                    </w:placeholder>
                    <w:text/>
                </w:sdtPr>
```

I work with this part of code, I must show user (Console.WriteLine) all "*Some text*" when tag = "number"

```
<w:alias w:val="Some text"/>
<w:tag w:val="number"/>
```

I will be glad for any help!

Comment: Is this your entire document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for can be neatly accomplished using lineq

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("D:\\test.xml");

XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";

var aliases = from stdPr in doc.Descendants(ns + "sdtPr")
            where (string)stdPr.Element(ns + "tag").Attribute(ns + "val") == "number"
            select (string)stdPr.Element(ns + "alias").Attribute(ns + "val");

foreach(var alias in aliases)
    Console.WriteLine(alias);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq :

```
sing System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> sdtPr = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "sdtPr").ToList();
            XNamespace ns = sdtPr.First().GetNamespaceOfPrefix("w");

            XElement number = sdtPr.Where(x => (string)x.Element(ns + "tag").Attribute(ns + "val") == "number").FirstOrDefault();

            foreach (XElement element in number.Elements())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name : '{0}', Value : '{1}'", element.Name.LocalName, (string)element.Attribute(ns + "val"));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```